# Got Android Studio installation error

Tags: windows, android-studio

I am kinda new to Android Studio & stuff. So today, I was installing the Android Studio with the SDK Manager. All was going smooth until an error came up which says:

Unable to install Intel HAXM
Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM).
Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization.
Here are some of your options:

1. Use a physical device for testing
2. Develop on a Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor that
   supports VT-x and NX
3. Develop on a Linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM
4. Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image    (This
   is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization)

I've attached a pic of my system specs. Can someone please throw some light on this issue?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is because you had not intialize virtual technology in your device.You Need to go in BOOT Option before starting WINDOWS OS and enable VT-x from there>

**The option of enabling Virtual technology is putted in different option depends on device manufacturer**

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Android Studio emulator won't run on Windows with an AMD processor. The error message is kind of misleading, as it suggests the problem is with your CPU. But it is within the troubleshoot message: "Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor". Basicallly, that means it is not going to work properly in your current setup. Either try installing Linux and running Android Studio on that (which might come with its own issues), using a physical device for testing or use the slow ARM images.

---

You are using an AMD processor. [SVM is AMD technology and VT-x is Intel technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#AMD_virtualization_.28AMD-V.29). So you won't be able to get VT-x to run, but SVM might be possible.

As another poster had suggested, virtualization may have been disabled in the BIOS. There may be an option to enable virtualization. It does however seem to happen that virtualization is activated in the BIOS and Android-Studio does not recognize that. I have not figured out how to fix that either.

You could use the emulator with an ARM image, which will be very slow. Alternatively, you could use another emulator that is not integrated into Android-Studio.